# Question on instantiating a function constructor with an eventListener

Tags: javascript, function, events, prototype, instantiation

I'm creating a simple book list app. It has 3 input fields (title, author, and isbn). I have a submit event on the form element. I might be having a brain fart or something, but I'm curious how I'm able to instantiate a new book ( const book = new Book(title, author, isbn); )
every time the submit event is triggered. Wouldn't I just be declaring the same variable over and over again? Simple answer I assume, but for the life of me I can't remember how this works.

```
// Event Listeners for add book
document.getElementById('book-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  // Getting form values
  const title = document.getElementById('title').value,
    author = document.getElementById('author').value,
    isbn = document.getElementById('isbn').value;

  // Instantiate a book
  const book = new Book(title, author, isbn);

  // Instantiate a UI Object
  const ui = new UI();

  debugger;

  // Validate
  if(title === '' || author === '' || isbn === '') {
    // Error alert
    ui.showAlert('Please fill in all fields', 'error');
  } else {
    // Add book to list
    ui.addBookToList(book);
    // Show success
    ui.showAlert('Book Added!', 'success');
    // Clear inputs
    ui.clearInputs();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: _Wouldn't I just be declaring the same variable over and over again?_ || It appears to be the very same variable but isn't because of the nature of closures. Each time the event handler is fired it creates a new closure that acts like a protected bubble. So each iteration has a different version of the same "looking" thing. you can think of these closures as a big multiverse.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your `Book` and `UI` code?  I think that the issue is in your UI logic, creating always a new instance you loose the reference to the list, and you should see only the latest book

Comment: // Book Constructor
function Book(title, author, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}


// UI Constructor
function UI() {}

Comment: This is a hard question to word. Every time the submit event is fired it instantiates a book. ( const book = new Book (title, author, isbn) ). Why does the code run if I'm declaring book ( const book ) each time the submit event is fired?

Comment: Each time you call the function it creates a new execution context. Any variables declared in the function exist only within that execution context, brand new ones are created on each call. And the listener should also `return false`.

Comment: @RobG Ahhh okay, that makes perfect sense! Thank you.

Comment: @BerryCoder—it's all in [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-executable-code-and-execution-contexts), but it might take a few reads to get it. Certainly good stuff if you can't sleep. :-)